# After upgrading from 22.10 to 23.04, how do I clean up my software and updates in the "Other Software" list?

Tags: support

Good evening to all of you. I was wondering, when I upgraded my Ubuntu OS from version 22.10 to version 23.04 I noticed that in "`Software & Updates >> Other Software`" there were all these old repositories of the previous version (the 22.10 in fact) already without confirmation tick.

Reading around on other forums many of you advised to edit (for example through nano) the file in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Here, I followed those steps, and, in the file, there were only the links to the repositories of the latest version (23.04), while the links to the old repositories are not present (or at most the link is preceded by a `#`).

Do you still recommend removing (using the "Remove" option) these old PPA's or do you recommend leaving them where they are?

Thanks a lot, to everyone.

*(link of the image where the problem is represented)*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n06s1.png

Answer (score 2):

It is safe to delete ("remove") unused sources from an older release of Ubuntu. They have no further use.

Do NOT disable or delete the `<release>`, `<release>-updates` or `<release>-security` sources for the **current** release that you are running. You need those. Everything else is optional.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. So if I understand correctly, can I remove them without any side effects (from "Installation medium Ubuntu 22.10 'Kinetic Kudu' to "Important security updates")?

Comment: @MarcoMarco if your sources meet the criteria of the first sentence of this answer (unused, older), then the rest of the sentence ("safe to delete") applies. It's really that simple. Apt sources are not mysterious or special at all; they are simply the URLs that apt will look for software. If you are worried, then write them down before deleting; they are trivial to re-add.